# How to save a snapshot of Azure Synapse SQL Pool (Data Warehouse) in another Active Directory Subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, restore, backup-strategies, azure-synapse

There is a data warehouse (Azure Synapse SQL Pool) in Azure Active Directory (ABC).
For learning purpose, we wanted to create same copy in another Azure Active Directory (XYZ).

Currently, I couldn't find any option to save the restore point in storage account.

Is there a way to save a restore point in storage account and then restore it from there in target resource group ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to use a `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT` [statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-cetas?) to export tables to files in Azure storage. Then script out the external tables and apply them to your second DW. Then read from the external tables to read data into your second DW.